# Custom User Provider Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions

Hi I'm trying to add a permissions check from the [laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) library to the web guarded routes.

I have tried to change the user provider so that i can override the method **validateCredentials** to check the eloquent credentials and then check if there are permissions.

However it seems that you can't change the driver in config/auth.php from database or eloquent, i just get an exception due to this check in

> Illuminate/Auth/CreatesUserProviders.php line 24

```
/**
     * Create the user provider implementation for the driver.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $provider
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider|null
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function createUserProvider($provider = null)
    {
        if (is_null($config = $this->getProviderConfiguration($provider))) {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($this->customProviderCreators[$driver = ($config['driver'] ?? null)])) {
            return call_user_func(
                $this->customProviderCreators[$driver], $this->app, $config
            );
        }

        switch ($driver) {
            case 'database':
                return $this->createDatabaseProvider($config);
            case 'eloquent':
                return $this->createEloquentProvider($config);
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                    "Authentication user provider [{$driver}] is not defined."
                );
        }
    }
```

How are you meant to override this **validateCredentials** call? / allow for only users with a certain permission from [laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to login to the web guard